# WPF & MVVM: passing event args don't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have WPF MVVM app where I want to pass the event args into the ViewModel and it does not work. I went through the bunch of the similar topics found on this site and the others but no result.

This is my XAML inside the control:

```
<telerik:RadMap>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove" >
    <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="VM.SomeMethod"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</telerik:RadMap>
```

And inside of my ViewModel I have the method:

```
public void SomeMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

When I move mouse over the control it raises the exception saying that there is no appropriate signature for the method.

Then I also tried to use EventToCommandBehavior of telerik, like this:

```
<telerik:RadMap>
<telerik:EventToCommandBehavior ...>
...
```

And it complains that EventToCommandBehavior does not exist. I googled and found this EventToCommandBehavior even in the telerik documentation. So I have a guess that maybe this is a newer feature cause my telerik is from 2010.

Anyway, any suggestion on how to pass the event arguments to the ViewModel are welcome.

Comment: When using `EventToCommand` you need a `Binding to ICommand` on your `ViewModel`. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) might be helpful !

Comment: What if you remove "VM.": MethodName="SomeMethod" ?

Comment: I've never used telerik's  mvvm framework, but if it works anything like MVVM Light, there is a property called `PassEventArgsToCommand` that needs to be set.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: I should have read the question better. The default root of a binding expression is the DataContext of the UI element being bound, so VM.SomeCommand is being read as DataContext.VM.SomeCommand by the binding expression. VM.SomeCommand should be changed to just SomeCommand, since the DataContext of your view should be your ViewModel.

The Expression Blend interactivity framework does not support passing the event args to the command.  I would suggest using an MVVM framework.

With [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm), which Bradley Uffner mentioned, you could just do this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=SomeCommand}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

However if you are opposed to that idea for one reason or another, you can try the solution discussed [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/silverlight-commands-hacks-passing-eventargs-as-commandparameter-to-delegatecommand-triggered-by-eventtrigger).

Sample code from link:

```
public sealed class InvokeDelegateCommandAction : TriggerAction<DependencyObject>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(InvokeDelegateCommandAction), null);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(InvokeDelegateCommandAction), null);

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InvokeParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "InvokeParameter", typeof(object), typeof(InvokeDelegateCommandAction), null);

    private string commandName;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public object InvokeParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(InvokeParameterProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(InvokeParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)this.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public string CommandName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.commandName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.CommandName != value)
            {
                this.commandName = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        this.InvokeParameter = parameter;

        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            ICommand command = this.ResolveCommand();
            if ((command != null) && command.CanExecute(this.CommandParameter))
            {
                command.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
            }
        }
    }

    private ICommand ResolveCommand()
    {
        ICommand command = null;
        if (this.Command != null)
        {
            return this.Command;
        }
        var frameworkElement = this.AssociatedObject as FrameworkElement;
        if (frameworkElement != null)
        {
            object dataContext = frameworkElement.DataContext;
            if (dataContext != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo commandPropertyInfo = dataContext
                    .GetType()
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .FirstOrDefault(
                        p =>
                        typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) &&
                        string.Equals(p.Name, this.CommandName, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                    );

                if (commandPropertyInfo != null)
                {
                    command = (ICommand)commandPropertyInfo.GetValue(dataContext, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return command;
    }
}
```

Example usage from blog:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Foo option 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Foo option 2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Foo option 3" />
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged" >
            <Presentation:InvokeDelegateCommandAction 
                Command="{Binding SubmitFormCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=InvokeParameter}" />
        </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>                
</ComboBox>
```

Note: I have not tested the solution from this blog.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723947%28v=expression.40%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), I read

> The method being called must be a public method that takes no arguments and does not return a value or a public method whose signature matches that of an event handler.

If you don't specifically need `MouseEventArgs` information, you may try without parameters, or with:

```
public void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

My 2 cents...

Comment: Your 2 cents were mentioned in the initial topic and confirmed that it does not work

Comment: The difference between what I see in your post and what I proposed is the type of event args, which is `MouseEventArgs`in your case, and just `EventArgs` in mine. Is it what you tried? The thing is that maybe using `MouseEventArg`is too restrictive and the expected type is just `EventArgs`, which you could cast later in the event management back to `MouseEventArgs`